# window.location not working correctly in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I have a div which has an a inside it. I want to click on the div and follow the same url as the a. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="overview white getchildurl">
    <p class="w70">
    05-02-2011
    </p>
    <a class="button" href="details/">Details</a>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```

and I have this script:

```
$('.getchildurl').each(function() {     
    $(this).click(function() {
        var href = $(this).children('a').first().attr('href');
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

This works in Firefox 3.6, Chrome, Safari, but not in IE7 and IE8. It reloads the page, but stays on the same page. I checked the var href, it has the right url, but doesn't go there. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: Making it an absolute URL made it work. This is the new script:

```
$('.getchildurl').each(function() {     
    $(this).click(function() {
        var href = $(this).children('a').first().attr('href');
        var host = window.location.hostname;
        window.location = 'http://' + host + '/' + href;
    });
});
```

Comment: try to explicitly set the `href` property. `window.location.href = href;`

Comment: window.location.href may work 
!

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ACaKu/ Can you go there and check? A few things to try: remove the trailing slash from "details/",  `location.href = href`, use an absolute path. Try just typing `javascript: window.location='details/'; void(0);` from the url bar

Comment: window.location.href doesn't work as well. It works in all browsers except IE7/8. Removing the trailing slash is not an option, the url gets added dynamically, I don't control it's syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting this as a different answer because it is a different answer. How to work through problem with JavaScript instead of work through it with HTML and CSS.

Try changing your JavaScript to display and make sure the values are what you think they are

```
$(this).click(function() {
    var href = $(this).children('a').first().attr('href');
    alert(href)
    alert(href.length)
    window.location = href;
});
```

That will display the `href` and the `href` length. Make sure the length matches up. If the length is too big then that means there are hidden characters.

If you determine that the problem is due to syntax, many URL fixes/conversions can be done with JavaScript. For example, removing a trailing slash when there is one can be done with

```
$(this).click(function() {
    var href = $(this).children('a').first().attr('href');
    window.location = href.replace(/\/$/, '');
});
```

Also, the URL could be converted to an absolute URL using JavaScript if that is what will fix the problem. And any other troublesome or even invisible characters can be either removed or replaced.

**Can you post a web page** on the internet that we can access to see the issue on our own copies of IE? Can you post an HTML file that we can copy to our machine and view in a browser? Your comment on the other question tells me you have some sort of XHTML strict DOCTYPE. If one of us can make the issue happen on our end, it is more likely to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, I'm not 100% sure about it (how IE7+8 handle the `.location` object), but after all it's just an object.

Try to explicitly set the `href` property within the `location` object:

```
window.location.href = href;
```

Comment: It's worth a try, but I've never seen this be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Although the topic is old, it's not obsolete. I just had the same problem.

```
window.location = href;
```

works fine, if you put another command after that.

```
window.location = href;
return false;
```

This works for me and redirects with the correct URL. Hope this helps others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a direct answer to you question but I have two suggestions

1. <strike>You may just want to try to see if jQuery will handle it for you</strike>

   ```
   $(this).children('a').first().click()
   ```

   Edit: This did not solve the problem
2. Also you may just want to make the whole `<div` in to an `<a` tag with `style="display: block; text-decoration: none"`. You can use font colors and underlines to make the text inside look however you want. Also, this solution does not require JavaScript. and it also makes the whole div show as focused instead of just the a or nothing at all.

Comment: 1. I don't think this is a clean solution.
2. This is not an option, I cut down the HTML for the example. There are actually a lot more block elements inside the div, which means I would have to change all the block elements inside to a span, including the current a. That would make it a big mess.

Comment: @Gregory: OK, about item two: 2. `div`s, `p`s and other block tags will be just fine inside of an a as long as you use display:block on the outer a. the inner a would be changed into a u because it would no longer handle the click actions, it would just be there to look good. The outer a would handle the click actions.

Comment: I'm using a strict doctype, using block elements inside an a won't validate. I like my code clean.