# Window.location.replace is not working on IE 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have below Javascript code. This does not work on IE-7 at production Environment. Could any one assist me that why this is happen over the IE-7?

Is this issue occurred due to any IE security setting ?

Code:

```
var ajaxData="{URL}";     ** URL: {http://IP:PORT ? SID }

window.location.replace(ajaxData);
```

Comment: Can you check the console to see what `window.loation` is returning? the window.location object is differently constructed in different browsers. Also, this is working fine in other browsers?

Comment: how about just window.location = ajaxData; ?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? The URL location will not change unless you overwrite it with a new value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809025/window-location-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = ajaxData
```