# window.location.href not working on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a problem with window.location.href.

I'm trying to redirect to a page with the following code:

```
window.location.href = "juego.html"+'?modoJuego='+modoJuego+"&etapa="+etapa+"&rango="+rango;
```

It works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, however in IE10 the browser freezes and I have to restart it. Sometimes it redirect to the desired page, but the parameters do not pass through. I have been looking for a solution, for example this one:

[Window.Location Not Working In IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809025/window-location-not-working-in-ie)

But the proposed solution do not work for me.

Do somebody know how to deal with this?

Comment: Just use `window.location`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201809/ie-incompatability-with-window-location-href ?

Comment: For one, don't mix `"` and `'`.  For two, there is no need to add strings that are hardcoded(`juego.html"+'?modoJuego`).  `window.location.href = "juego.html?modoJuego="+modoJuego+"&etapa="+etapa+"&rango="+rango;`

Comment: What does your URL expand to? If any of your variables contain special or invalid characters you may need to wrap the right-hand side of your assignment in [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: windows.location produce the same result. The link of the second comment procduce the same result. I changed the string as suggested by David Starkey with the same result. Any other idea?

Comment: @André Dion: You were right, one of those parameters had some blank spaces. I removed them and now it work perfectly on IE10. Please post this as an answer so I can vote it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely due to the value of your variables. If they contain special or invalid characters, those needs to be passed through [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before being assigned to `window.location.href`.

Comment: Thanks André, just a little observation: the encodeURIComponent didn't worked to me, however, you were right about the thing of the special characters, I had some spaces on a variable, I remove them and now its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason IE only like full url.

I have te same problem and fix it adding the full url like this:

```
var baseURL = 'http://www.your_url.com/';

window.location.href = baseURL + "juego.html"+'?modoJuego='+modoJuego+"&etapa="+etapa+"&rango="+rango;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` to escape your url:

```
window.location.href = encodeURIComponent("juego.html?modoJuego=" + modoJuego + "&etapa=" + etapa + "&rango=" + rango);
```

Works fine on Firefox 23.0, Chrome 28.0.1500.95 and Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't worked. The problem was some spaces on the parameters, I removed them and now work fine.

Comment: No doubt that was the problem, the solution is to use `encodeURIComponent` in order to escape those illegal characters. Removing them altogether is avoiding the problem.

Comment: It didn't worked. I tried and that did not solve the problem. What solved the problem was to remove the characters manually (blank spaces on the parameters).

Comment: When encoding more than just parameters, you should use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) instead so reserved characters such as `=` aren't also encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.location.replace(...)` instead.

**Refer this question for information:**

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)