# How to redirect to an external URL

Tags: angularjs

When trying to redirect to an external page using `$window.location.href`, the page is just refreshing and not redirecting to the expected URL.

Comment: $window.location = 'www.newlocation';

Comment: eg. Inside the controller  used like this  e.g. $window.location = 'http://www.google.com' , but still it was not redirecting to new url.

Comment: it works for me. Are you injecting $window into your controller? Doss it give you any error on the console?

Comment: Could just use plain javascript... `window.open('google.com');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: pdmApp.controller('projectionDetailController', 
[
        '$log', 
 'projectionDetailService', 
 '$filter',
 '$window',
 '$location',
 '$scope',
 
    function ($log, pdService, $filter,$window,$location, $scope) {
 $scope.backToPreviousPage = function () 
 {

            $window.location = "http://www.google.com";
 }
}
});   it is still  not redirecting to external url e.g google.com

Comment: Tony- I have used window.open('google.com') , this opens a new browser window. is it possible to open in existing window.

Comment: @madh `window.open('google.com', '_blank')` I believe.

Comment: I saw this behavior happen when the URL was (literally) wrapped in quotes; even though I had "http://" in front of the URL. Removing the quotes fixed it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p> <a href="https://www.google.co.in/"><button>Click me to redirect from template</button></a></p>
    <p ng-click="myFunction()"> <button>Click me to redirect from controller</button></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($window,$scope){
        $scope.myFunction = function(){
        $window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //You should have http here.
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Alaksandar ... I tried the same way with $window.location.href , the page refreshing instead of redirect to expected url.

Comment: Are you sure that you got the http.Without http it will fall back your website only.

Comment: I am running under IISExpress(localhost)   eg.http://localhost:port/.../../sample.aspx

Comment: You are missing the http here $window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; with reference to your comments. Can you post your code of that $window.location

Comment: pdmApp.controller('projectionDetailController', 
[
    '$log', 
 'projectionDetailService', 
 '$filter',
 '$window',
 '$location',
 '$scope',
 
    function ($log, pdService, $filter,$window,$location, $scope) {
 $scope.backToPreviousPage = function () 
 {
            $window.location = 'http://localhost:port/../sample2.aspx';
 }
}
});

Comment: $window.location.href = "http://localhost:port/../sample2.aspx";; the http is missing out in comment. I will post as new answer

Comment: Hi,How will be the reverse navigation? From the remote url to localhost pages?

Answer (score 0):

```
pdmApp.controller('projectionDetailController', [ '$log', 'projectionDetailService', '$filter', '$window', '$location', '$scope', function ($log, pdService, $filter,$window,$location, $scope) { 

$scope.backToPreviousPage = function () { 
  alert("function is working"); //Add this line to your code to confirm your function is called.
$window.location.href = "http://localhost:port/../sample2.aspx";

} 

} //What is this bracket for?


}]); //you are missing this square bracket.
```

**Change To**

```
pdmApp.controller('projectionDetailController', ['$log', 'projectionDetailService', '$filter', '$window', '$location', '$scope', function($log, pdService, $filter, $window, $location, $scope) {
  $scope.backToPreviousPage = function() {
    alert("function is working"); //Add this line to your code to confirm your function is called.
    $window.location.href = "http://localhost:port/../sample2.aspx";
  };
]);
```

Comment: $window.location.href = "http://localhost:port/../sample2.aspx" , (included http)  but still not redirecting to expected url.

Comment: Add a alert inside the function to confirm whether the function is called. and check whether you are getting alert message. If you are getting it then post your view which fires the function. If you dont get alert then delete this projectionDetailService and pdService in controller.

Comment: yes. alert message is shown,. function is getting called.

Comment: Can you check your console whether you are getting any error. You are missing brackets.

Comment: Alaksandar - FYI, when I use window.open('http://google.com') it is opening the  url in new window. but $window.location.href is not working

Comment: How could your code is executed if you are missing a bracket. If you are changing contents  for confidential matters, then its ok. If not, it was supposed to throw error for that missing brackets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278777/window-location-href-not-working-on-ie

Comment: try with different browser.