# How to check if a value exists in AJAX success response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX.

```
   var id = "some_text";
   $.ajax({
        type        : "GET",  
        dataType    : "json",
        url         : "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/get_outlet'); ?>",  
        async       : false,
        success     : function(outlet){

           $.map(outlet, function (v) { 

              if(v.NamaOutlet == id){
                window.location.href = "page_a.php";
              }
              else{
                window.location.href = "page_b.php"; 
              }

           })
        }   
})
```

I'd like to check if the value of `id` is exist in the AJAX success call (JSON object type). If it exists, redirect to page A and if not redirect to page B. When I use `alert` on `v.NamaOutlet` the value is exist. But why am I not redirected to page_a.php?

**edit**

when I use `alert(JSON.stringify(outlet))`;

```
[{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"ACG","NamaOutlet":"Accounting"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"BBG","NamaOutlet":"Business Banking"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CB I","NamaOutlet":"Corporate Banking I"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CB II","NamaOutlet":"Corporate Banking II"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CBT","NamaOutlet":"Corporate & Branch Transformation"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CCG","NamaOutlet":"Culture & Customer Care"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CHG","NamaOutlet":"Consumer Finance & Hajj"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CMG","NamaOutlet":"Commercial Banking"}
```

Comment: I have use IF to check it.

Comment: what about your `php` code.

Comment: It's still in jQuery scoop. no php code is required.

Comment: You're using a `map` call on data and that will trigger the conditional based on the first object literal it reads from `outlet`. Did you configure `id` to match the first `NamaOutlet` value in the array (from what you posted that value is `Accounting`)?

Comment: @Mike not only the first. I'd like to check if `id` exist in all `NamaOutlet`

Comment: Is the desired behaviour that if "some_value" exists in *any* of the ids then redirect to A, and if it exists in *none* of the ids redirect to B?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes. if exist then A, else then B

Comment: why the answer is deleted? It keep redirect me to page_b even if `v_NamaOutlet == id` is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `window.location.href` doesn't immediately terminate the current script - I'm not sure how reliable this is cross browser, but in my testing in Chrome if you set `window.location.href` more than once in the same script the browser navigates to the *last* value set before the JS function ends.

So in your case it would navigate to the result of testing the last item in your array, because your `$.map()` loop runs the if/else for every item in the array.

You could instead use your loop to set a flag to indicate whether the item was found anywhere in the array:

```
    success     : function(outlet){
       var idFound = false;
       $.each(outlet, function (v) { 
          if(v.NamaOutlet == id){
            idFound = true;
          }
       });
       window.location.href = idFound ? "page_a.php" : "page_b.php";
    }
```

Note that I've used `$.each()`, because although `$.map()` would achieve the same result it doesn't really make sense because you're not really doing any mapping.

You can tidy this up and remove the need for a flag variable by using the [array `.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) rather than `$.each()`:

```
    success     : function(outlet){
       if (outlet.some(function(v) { return v.NamaOutlet == id; })) {
          window.location.href = "page_a.php";
       else {
          window.location.href = "page_b.php";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason I could find here is that you might be using Internet Explorer and internet explorer does not really accept relative URLs as mentioned in one of the answers here
[window.location.href not working on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278777/window-location-href-not-working-on-ie)

Rest all seems good. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using Firefox

Answer (score 0):

TRY IT:

```
            var id = "Business Banking";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/get_outlet'); ?>",
                async: false,
                success: function (outlet) {

                    //[{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"ACG","NamaOutlet":"Accounting"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"BBG","NamaOutlet":"Business Banking"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CB I","NamaOutlet":"Corporate Banking I"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CB II","NamaOutlet":"Corporate Banking II"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CBT","NamaOutlet":"Corporate & Branch Transformation"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CCG","NamaOutlet":"Culture & Customer Care"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CHG","NamaOutlet":"Consumer Finance & Hajj"},{"KodeOutlet_iBSM":"CMG","NamaOutlet":"Commercial Banking"}]

                    var exist = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < outlet.length; i++) {

                        if (outlet[i].NamaOutlet === id) {
                            exist = true;
                            break;
                        }


                    }
                    if (exist) {
                        window.location.href = "page_a.php";

                    } else {
                        window.location.href = "page_b.php";

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: This works. but `var exist = true` should be `var exist;`.

Comment: `var exist = false;` would make more sense than `undefined` as a default, though either would work.

Comment: if I'd like to store `window.location.href = "page_a.php` to a  variable `link`. How can I use it outside AJAX call?

Comment: My error. Variable exist should be false on initialized. I updated it.

Comment: Yes you can use this outside after ajax call , but you need use alway async=false. do you need that i update the example ?

Answer (score 0):

if else condition is not suitable for your situation , let your `id` is *Commercial Banking* ,the last array value of your given json response .So mapping json will be check first index with `id` ,so if not equal it redirected to `page_b` .But you have `id` that exist in `json response` so that condition is not true for your condition . You wanna check `id` is exist in `outlet` so that map `json array` and if it found redirected page , if not found write the redirect other page in next execute line....

```
   var id = "Commercial Banking"; // eg value
   $.ajax({
        type        : "GET",  
        dataType    : "json",
        url         : "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/get_outlet'); ?>",  
        async       : false,
        success     : function(outlet){

           $.map(outlet, function (v) {
              if(v.NamaOutlet == id){
                window.location.href = "page_a.php";
              }    
           });
           window.location.href = "page_b.php";                   
        }   
 });
```

Comment: Wouldn't this always set `.href = "page_b.php"` because that line runs after the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#btn').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/Contrller/Action Name',
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json;",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        console.log(r);
                        if (r == true) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: '/Contrller/Action',
                                data: {  },
                                contentType: "application/json;",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (r) {
                                    $("#btnclosem").trigger("click")
                                    var select = $("#Div");
                                    select.empty();
               select.append($('<option/>', {value: 0,text: "" }));  $.each(r.list, function (index, itemData) {
}
                            });
                            return false;

                        }
                        else {
                            alert("")
                            return false;

                        }
                    }
                });
```