# How make td element clickable, and make it working in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I get this code to make a td element clickable. It works fine in FF and Chrome but it doesn't work in IE. How can I improve this code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("td div.node-bloques-el-inicio").click(function(){

    window.location = $(this).find("h2 a").attr("href");
  });

});
```

capture of the code: [capture](http://content.screencast.com/users/chefnelone/folders/Snagit/media/32d96eca-883d-464f-9324-702989cad33d/2013-03-08_11-48-13.png)

Comment: this code is absolutely fine.. :)

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the table?

Comment: and which version of IE you are using?

Comment: I guess it`s an IE problem, have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818868/window-location-not-working-correctly-in-ie7-8)

Comment: yes, the problem just happens in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is syntactically correct. Given the jQuery selectors in it, I'm assuming your HTML structure is as follows?

```
<table>
    ...
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            <div class="node-bloques-el-inicio">
                <h2>
                    <a href="http://mysite.com">This is a link</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </td>
        ...
    ...
</table>
```

If it is, your code should work in cross-browser. If this is you your HTML structure, please elaborate the question.

Comment: Thanks for fiddling it :) However, I think because the issue is in IE, if it's 8 or older, the issue might be in `window.location =`. I've had some issues with changing the page via javascript in IE8 and below.

Comment: Could you also let us know the href attribute? If it is an IE issue with using `window.location =`, I'm guessing you're using a local URL? (as in `/Module/Register.apsx` as opposed to a **full** URL (`http://www...`))

Comment: My mistake, as all of you said it was fine. Was a cache issue. Thanks.